# Kafka Replication factor JMX

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx

I'm trying to collect some Kafka `Telemetry` when I do some replication of my messages.

I presume my bottleneck is in the network when I do replication of the record in 3 instances `RF=3`

I need data to support my theory, so do we have any `JMX` data that can tell me in `Grafana` how much time it takes a record to be replicated in the three machines.

Regards.

Comment: I assume you mean using Prometheus / JMX exporter? Grafana is a UI, not a metric gatherer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `kafka.network:type=RequestMetrics` metrics. There's a few metrics that track the time spent processing produce requests on the leader and the time spent waiting for followers to replicate records. They are highlighted in the [Monitoring section](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#monitoring) in the Kafka docs:

- `kafka.network:type=RequestMetrics,name=TotalTimeMs,request=Produce`: Total time spent processing produce requests
- `kafka.network:type=RequestMetrics,name=LocalTimeMs,request=Produce`: Time spent by the leader processing produce requests
- `kafka.network:type=RequestMetrics,name=RemoteTimeMs,request=Produce`: Time spent waiting for followers

There are a few other metrics including `RequestQueueTimeMs`, `ResponseQueueTimeMs`, `ResponseSendTimeMs` each measuring the different steps brokers take when handling requests.

All of these metrics have a few attributes such as various percentiles, min, max, etc, that you should monitor to identify potential bottlenecks in your clusters.